# Given two polynomials, determine two other degrees through polynomial division

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

I read in a proof, where it says something in this direction

> Divide any polynomial $Q$ of degree $2n-2$ by $P$ (of degree $n$) and get an equation $Q=SP+R$ with $S$ and $R$ polynomials of degree at most $n-2$ and $n-1$, respectively.

If two polynomials $P,Q$ are given with $\deg Q=2n-2$ and $\deg P=n$, it is well-known that we can write $Q=SP+R$ for some unique polynomials of $S$ and $R$ with $\deg R<\deg S$. The question is, how do you see that $\deg S\leq n-2$ and $\deg R\leq n-1$, as stated above?

Comment: It should be $\mathrm{deg}R<\mathrm{deg}P$, so $\mathrm{deg} R\le n-1$. For example, $P=x^2$, $Q=x^2+x=1(x^2)+x$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Oh ... that's the mistake I couldn't spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of degrees of $S$ and $P$ must equal to the degree of $Q$ so $$\deg S +n = 2n-2\implies \deg S = n-2$$

Since $\deg R < \deg P=n$ we have $\deg R\leq n-1$.

Comment: How do you know that $\deg (SP)=\deg Q$; couldn't it be $\geq $ instead of $=\ $?

Comment: No, if $S(x) = ax^k+...$ and $P(x)=bx^n+...$ (dots are for lower terms), then $P(x)S(x) = abx^{k+n}+...$, so $n+k = ?$

Comment: Okay, so it is not being affected by the degree of $R$, simply because that its degree is lower than of $P$ or $Q$, or ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to tell me in last comment but $R$ has no influence on the degree of $S$.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this one: $\deg Q=\deg(SP + R)\leq \max\{\deg SP,\deg R\} = \deg S + n$, which implies that $\deg S\leq n-2$?

Comment: No, it is not.......... but it is actually $\deg (SP+R) = \max ...$

Comment: You don't have to accept my answer if you are not satisfied. Perhaps you will get ''better'' explanation. Instead you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

an example....

$$  \left(   x^{8}  + 2 x^{7}  + 3 x^{6}  + 4 x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 7 x^{2}  + 8 x  + 9 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  +  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{8}  + 2 x^{7}  + 3 x^{6}  + 4 x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 7 x^{2}  + 8 x  + 9 \right)  =  \left(   x^{5}  +  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  +  x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left(   x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  + 6 x  + 8 \right)  $$